# string.find versus this function

Tags: c++, strings

I got bored and decided to write my own function to verify if a string contains another string.

I was wondering if there's any major difference between these two function except the one I wrote being more complicated.

```
bool Contains(string str, string find){
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - (find.length()-1); i++){
        if (find.length() > 0){
            int CharactersFound = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < find.length(); x++){
                if (str[i + x] == find[x]){
                    CharactersFound++;
                }
                else {
                    CharactersFound = 0;
                }
            }
            if (CharactersFound == find.length()) return true;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
bool StrContains(string str, string find){
    if (str.find(find) != string::npos) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I guess we need to assume `#include <string>` and `using std::string;`?  It's best to include these in the question, both to avoid misunderstandings, and to make it easier to compile your code and any subsequent improvements.  A small suggestion (not big enough for a full answer) is that both your arguments should be taken by const reference rather than by copy.

Comment: If you are interested in algorithms, I would suggest that you have a look at trie based search strategies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's likely to be a difference between the two.

Specifically, the version using `std::string::find` is likely to be faster in most typical cases. In particular, the version you wrote continues to iterate through a possible match at a given position, even when it's found a mismatch so there can't be a match at that position. Although I doubt it's prohibited, I'd be quite surprised to see `std::string::find` display this behavior.

Looking at your wrapper around `std::string::find`, I think I'd write it a bit differently, more like:

```
bool StrContains(string str, string find){
    return str.find(find) != string::npos;
}
```

This seems simpler, at least to me.

If I were going to implement a `find` function, I think I'd start with a `compare` function to see if I had a match at a given location:

```
template <class InItr>
bool compare(InItr a, InItr bb, InItr be) { 
     while (bb != be && *a == *be) {
         ++a;
         ++be;
     }
     return bb == be;
}
```

The idea here is pretty simple: walk through the two strings until we either reach the end of the second string, or find a mismatch between the two strings. Then we return a value to indicate whether we found a mismatch, or reached the end of the string.

With that, we can see whether one contains the other much more easily: we just look at each possible location. If we found a match, we return true. If we reach the end without finding a match, we return false:

```
bool strContains(string str, string find) { 
     if (find.empty())
         return true;

     if (find.length() > str.length())
         return false;

    auto last_loc = str.length() - find.length() + 1;

    for (std::string::size_type i=0; i<last_loc; i++)
        if (compare(str.cbegin() + i, find.cbegin(), find.cend())
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

I'm not sure this will really be faster to any practical degree, but (at least assuming the compiler can expand `compare` inline) I'd guess it's at least as fast, and I find it easier to understand.

Comment: I'm not convinced that you can test `*b` to determine end-of-string with a `std::string` as you can for a C string - can you find a reference that says `*s.end()` is legal and returns a false value?

Comment: @TobySpeight: Before C++11, NUL termination wasn't guaranteed. Since then, it pretty much is. I see what I think is a way to read the standard as not quite requiring it, but general consensus seems against me on this, and since the rest of the world treats it as required, I don't see much reason we shouldn't treat it that way too.

Comment: @Jerry - that seems to be true only for access via `data()` - I think it's still invalid to dereference the `end()` iterator.  If I'm wrong, I'd love to know, as your code is simpler than what I would write in my current state of knowledge.

Comment: cppreference says of `end()` and `cend()`: *"Returns an iterator to the character following the last character of the string. This character acts as a placeholder, attempting to access it results in undefined behavior."*

Comment: @TobySpeight: A string is a contiguous container **[basic.string]**. A contiguous container supports random access iterators whose member types iterator and const_iterator are contiguous iterators. **[container.requirements.general]**. For contiguous iterators `*(a + n) is equivalent to *(addressof(*a) + n)` **[iterator.requirements.general]**

Comment: @TobySpeight: An iterator returned by end() is a `past-the-end values`. I can not find anything that says de-referencing these values is undefined behavior. But the standard does say this **<quote>The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable.</quote>** This to me implies that are situations that it can be valid its just the library is never going to take that chance.

Comment: @TobySpeight: There is a real danger in how I've written `compare`, but it's more or less the reverse of the issue you raised: not that you're likely to cause a problem by dereferencing past the end of the string, but that you'll terminate early, because it's entirely possible to store a '\0' *inside* a string without it actually signifying the string's end. Fixing this has removed the other issue as well.

Comment: Yes, I see you now only dereference the past-the-end when `a` finishes before `b` (and yes, in practice, it's likely to be safe in real implementations).

Comment: @TobySpeight: We assure that we never invoke `compare` in a way that `a` could finish before `b`.

Comment: Oh, yes, missed that!  Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

There's likely a difference in your implementation and the library's. The algorithm you used is an inefficient variant of the inefficient brute force algorithm (yes, doubly inefficient). Better algorithms exist for finding a substring, for example the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). I suspect the library uses something more clever than brute force.

---

It's strange and inefficient to have the `find.length() > 0` inside the loop. The value of `find.length()` doesn't change inside the loop, so it's better to check it once, before the loop begins.

---

Counting the characters found is inefficient if you don't break on a mismatch.
Instead of counting the characters found, it would be better to use a boolean flag. When you find a character that doesn't match, you can set the flag and break out of the loop. After the loop, if the flag changed, you know the string wasn't found.

That is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - (find.length()-1); i++) {
    bool mismatch = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < find.length(); x++) {
        if (str[i + x] != find[x]){
            mismatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!mismatch) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Instead of using a flag, what's even better is to extract the inner loop to a function, as Jerry-Coffin did.

---

You can use boolean expressions directly as return values. So instead of this:

> ```
> if (str.find(find) != string::npos) return true;
> return false;
> ```

You can write:

```
return str.find(find) != string::npos;
```

---

There are multiple accepted naming conventions in C++,
but I don't think there is when where local variables follow `PascalCase`. It would be better to change to `camelCase`.

Comment: As a side note: it's unlikely that the standard library uses KMP (or a BM variant) for string searching. These require enough setup that they're generally only justified if/when you know the search strings involved are long (for some definition of "long"). It could decide what to use based on length, but I've never seen one actually do that.